# Html5 filereader - read local Json Array file and display only a specific section

Tags: javascript, json, filereader

I'm a beginner and come form VBA excel programming tool.
Reading excel file, manipulating excel content is a lot easier in VBA than the web tool like Filereader and Json array.

I have the following content in my Json array file.

```
[
  ["TWE",6000,4545.5  ],
  ["RW",1000,256.3  ]
]
```

I would like to read from the following html file and display only the value 253.6

Can you help me.

Here the Html file reader example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>        
            function handleFileSelect()
            {               
                if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

                } else {
                    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
                    return;
                }   

                input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
                if (!input) {
                  alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
               }
               else if (!input.files) {
                  alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
               }
               else if (!input.files[0]) {
                  alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
               }
               else {
                  file = input.files[0];
                  fr = new FileReader();
                  fr.onload = receivedText;
                  fr.readAsText(file);
               }
            }

            function receivedText() {           
               //result = fr.result;
               document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result))
            }           

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
        <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='handleFileSelect();'>
        <div id="editor"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can, please link to your document? Maybe the short version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you get the text with fr.readAsText into a string, you can use JSON.parse() (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the string into a JSON object. Then you can access your specific content like a normal array.

Comment: Thank a lot it works. Here the additional code I did add under " receivedText"function                                                                                                                        function receivedText() {           
               //result = fr.result;
               var newArr = JSON.parse(fr.result);
               alert(newArr[1][2]);